# SQL - Improving JOIN query (Taking long time to load)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, pdo

I have below query, which I believe I have optimized as much as I possible could:

```
SELECT 
        c.forum_id as category_id,
        c.forum_name as category_name,
        t.forum_id as id,
        t.forum_name as name,
        t.forum_desc as description,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND topic_deleted=0) as topics_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=lp.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as last_post_count,
        lp.topic_id as last_post_topic_id,
        lp.topic_title as last_post_topic_title,
        lp.post_time as last_post_time,
        lp.username as last_post_username,
        lp.avatar
    FROM forum_cats as t
    JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id
    left join (
        SELECT 
            ft.topic_id,
            ft.title as topic_title,
            tmp.post_time,
            u.username,
            u.avatar,
            fp.forum_id
        FROM
            forum_posts fp
            join forum_topics ft on ft.topic_id = fp.topic_id
            join users u on u.id = fp.userid
            join (
                select forum_id, max(`post_time`) `post_time`
                from forum_posts fp
                where fp.post_deleted = 0
                group by forum_id
                ) as tmp on (fp.forum_id = tmp.forum_id and fp.post_time = tmp.post_time)
        where post_deleted = 0 and ft.topic_deleted = 0
    ) as lp on lp.forum_id = t.forum_id
    where t.forum_active = 1 and c.forum_active = 1
    order by category_id, t.forum_id
```

This is the stats for each forum:

```
    forum_cats has 20 rows
    forum_topics has 900 rows
    forum_posts has 9000 rows
    users has 18000 rows
```

I have added `index` on all the columns that is being selected in above query. Yet it still takes more than 2 seconds to execute this.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Remove those two sub-joins and make them into a temp table. That should speed things up for you.

Comment: Hey! Do you mind giving an example? Thanks!

Comment: this kind of question without EXPLAIN output is just pointless

Comment: @oliverbj Update your question , so that understand question clearly, Show your 4 tables with example data and show the expected data from them , Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't `topics_count`, `posts_count` & `last_post_count` be the same for every row? Wouldn't it be more efficient to pull these values separately, rather than make the same 3 calculations for every row you pull?

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. Would you mind updating it with how it would look like? Sorry, but this is the only way I can think of doing it. Always helpful with a new set of eyes =)